# Passing the output of a statement to a statement in Octave. Why does sprintf modify data?

Tags: matlab, printf, octave

I would like to understand the following behavior of Octave.

**How does `sprintf` work?**

When padding a **floating point** number with *10 digits*:

```
$ ans = 2;
$ sprintf('%10.3f',ans)
ans =      2.000
$ sprintf('%10.3f',ans)
ans =     32.000    32.000    32.000    32.000    32.000    50.000    46.000    48.000    48.000    48.000
```

When passing a **floating point** with precision of *`3` decimal digits:*

```
$ ans = 2
ans =  2
$ sprintf('%0.3f',ans)
ans = 2.000
$ sprintf('%0.3f',ans)
ans = 50.00046.00048.00048.00048.000
```

When passing an **integer**:

```
$ ans = 2
ans =  2
$ sprintf('%d',ans)
ans = 2
$ sprintf('%d',ans)
ans = 50
```

***Why does that value of `ans` change when passing to `sprintf`?
Shouldn't it just pass a formatted output without modifying the data?***

Comment: I vaguely remember ans as a special variable in octave. Does the weird behaviour go away if you call the variable X instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ans` is just a place holder for the result of the most recently run command. The issue here is that`sprintf` returns a **string**, not an integer or a float. So when you call

```
$ sprintf('%d',ans)
ans = 2
```

`ans` is acutally the character `'2'` which has [an ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com/) of `50` and your next call specifically tells `sprintf` to consider the input as an integer hence it outputs `50`. Try this instead:

```
$ sprintf('%d',ans)
ans = 2
$ sprintf('%s',ans) % i.e. tell sprintf to expect a string (%s) and not an integer (%d)
ans = 2
```

So considering another example from your question:

```
$ ans = 2
ans =  2
$ sprintf('%0.3f',ans)
ans = 2.000
$ sprintf('%0.3f',ans)
ans = 50.00046.00048.00048.00048.000
```

now the second call to `sprintf` is equivalent to `sprintf('%0.3f','2.000')` and if you cast the string `2.000` to integers you'll get `[50, 46, 48, 48, 48]`. You can prove this to yourself by typing `uint8('2.000')` in the command line.